# Cómo hago una lista de flotantes con cualquier número de datos?

Tags: python

Andaba haciendo ejercicios pero me tope con uno que no me sale. Me piden hacer una función que, de entrada reciba una lista de números flotantes y los imprima. La lista debe almacenar todos los flotantes que el usuario quiera. Intenté hacer el código con un `for` y me hacia la lista, pero cuando ingreso un flotante me aparece error, aun cuando ya le especifique que haga la conversión a flotante. Agradezco su ayuda este es el código que intente hacer.

```
def lista():
    li = []
    valores = (input("peso: "))
    for valor in valores:
        li.append(valor)
    return li
print(lista())
```

Comment: el ejercicio es con lenguaje python

Comment: tienes algun error? o el resultado no es el esperado?. Describe mejor tu problema

Comment: cuando ingreso los numeros flotantes me aparece este error: could not convert string to float: '.', pero yo le agrego el float: li.append(float(valor), y aun asi no reconoce el flotante

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu código no esta del todo mal, solo hace falta tomar en cuenta algo (que es lo que origina el problema), al ejecutar tu código lo mas probable es que el resultado sea una lista de Strings algo como `['2','','2','0','','3','.','1']` teniendo como input `2 20 3.1`.

El input te regresa la cadena, per ¿Cómo sabemos cual es el numero o los numero?, bueno si ingresas los números separados por algún delimitador (en este caso espacios) podemos decir que un numero es aquel que esta seguido de un espacio. Para hacer la separación utilizamos la función `split()`, la cual nos devuelve una lista con cada numero, luego utilizamos la función `float()` para convertirlo a un numero flotante. Quedando tu código así:

```py
def lista():
    li = []
    valores = input("peso: ")
    valores = valores.split()#por defecto separa por espacios 
    for valor in valores:
        li.append(float(valor))#agregaos a la lista
    return li
print(list())
```

La función `split()` acepta como parámetro el carácter a separa, si tu quieres que el input sea `2,3,3.1` solo tenemos que cambiar el parametro de la función `split()` a `split(",")` .

**Probamos**

```
peso: 10 20 2 2.2
[10.0, 20.0, 2.0, 2.2]
```

Tu código se puede simplificar con una compresión de lista, esto es un ciclo for pero *"abreviado"*

```py
def lista():
    valores = input("peso: ")
    valores = valores.split()
    li = [float(num) for nun in valores]
    return li
print(lista())
```

por cierto recuerda que para indicar la parte decimal de un numero se utiliza el punto `.`, si colocas `2,3` y lo conviertes a float esto dará un error.

Comment: joder amigo te mereces el cielo muchas gracias :,3

Comment: jeje de nada :)